# Fridge Leveling Issue (Kenmore Pro 79993)

Tags: refrigerator

I recently had a Kenmore Pro 79993 refrigerator installed. While my floor i level, the fridge itself appears not to be (the front is a little over 1/4 inch higher than the back). There are leveling legs in the front, but they can only raise it further.

According to the [manual page 10](http://i.sears.com/s/d/pdf/mp-tc/10099713/prod_1571627712) (emphasis mine):

> To avoid noise and vibration, **the unit must be leveled** and installed on a solidly constructed floor. [...] **The front should be slightly higher than the rear** to aid in door closing.

However, there is no indication of how much higher than front should be. I've done a bit more research with mixed results - some people (including friends) have mentioned that all fridges should be completely level otherwise the hinges might get messed up. Others have said that anywhere between 1/4" - 1/2" difference between front and back is acceptable.

It also seems like the only way to raise the back is with shims, making it seem like the manufacturer *did* intend for the front to be higher.

I'm just trying to make sure that the fridge has been installed correctly and that it won't be damaged due to being off level.

Comment: The instructions SAY to set the front slightly higher than the rear, and why.  You just quoted them.  Following those instructions is mandatory (NEC 110.3B).  Good on them for building it in!!!  Seriously, you will want the front tilt - you want doors that close smartly, not kinda almost close and you're never sure.  Trust me on that!

Comment: I guess it was just a case of listening too much to random people on the Internet and getting worried ;) I just wish they specified *how much higher* the front should be to put my mind at ease. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the instructions you just posted is that it is obvious the manufacturer intends for the unit to be installed with a slight backward tilt (front feet higher).  In fact, they did you the courtesy of building it in.

Believe me, you don't want a refrigerator with lazy doors that you can't quite ever trust to shut properly.  You want a door that closes smartly and with authority, without you having to worry about it, hand-guide it all the way shut, or double check it.

For what it's worth, NEC 110.3B make manufacturer instructions like this actually mandatory.  You could argue it'd be illegal to defeat the intentional front lift.